# Question slug doesn't account for upper case accented characters in title

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, title, special-characters

The title of a Stack Exchange question is included (for SEO purposes) in the 'canonical' URL for the question. In this process, symbols are removed and the title is lower cased, but the latter part fails for accented characters. The question [Dibujar Árbol de búsqueda Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/212061/22845) on the Spanish Stack Overflow site has a slug `dibujar-Árbol-de-búsqueda-python`; one would expect that to be `dibujar-árbol-de-búsqueda-python`.